# Python: How to assign the parameter in 'def' as a fixed value

Tags: python, function

does anyone know if I can assign a parameter to a function name ? I want to loop through a various of stock symbol through a fixed set of codes. I thought using 'def' as a way to simplified it.

At the end of the day, I want to have all the dataframe for different stock symbols. I thought by assigning the 'Symbol'(parameter) as a function name in the code, I can 'locked' in the name for different dataframe. For example, if I will to code AAPL.head(), I can get the dataframe for AAPL. However, it does not seem to be working as I got an error 'name 'AAPL' is not defined'

If this is not working, can someone advise how to build something like that. I hope I make sense.

```
def my_function (Symbol):

    Symbol = df[df['Date_time'] >= str(onedayago)]
    
my_function('AAPL')
my_function('MSFT')
.....
```

Comment: You're passing something in and then immediately overwriting to that name, and you're not returning anything. You might want to do some more reading about functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work, for lots of reasons.

If you want to create variables with arbitrary names, the easiest way is to create them as keys inside a dictionary:

```
stocks = {}
stocks['AAPL'] = something...
stocks['MSFT'] = something else...
```